# Invalid manifest: unknown fields: [addOns.enableHttpEndpoints]

Tags: google-apps-script, runtime, alternate, google-workspace-add-ons

I am trying to use google workspace alternate runtime, which requires a key `enableHttpEndpoints` in the manifest to work by when try to save it with that keys it gives me error.

below is my manifest:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "enableHttpEndpoints": true,
    "common": {
      "name": "My HTTP Add-on",
      "logoUrl": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/googlematerialicons/markunread_mailbox/v6/black-24dp/1x/gm_markunread_mailbox_black_24dp.png",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "https://us-central1-test-http-runtime.cloudfunctions.net/HttpAddOn/exampleWidgets"
      }
    },
    "gmail": {
      
      "contextualTriggers": [{
        "unconditional": {
        },
        "onTriggerFunction": "https://us-central1-test-http-runtime.cloudfunctions.net/GmailExample/simpleMessageInfo"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

and the error it gives:

> Invalid manifest: unknown fields: [addOns.enableHttpEndpoints]

Comment: Alternate Runtimes for Google Workspace Add-ons is still in a beta version - did you sign up in order to become a beta tester?

Comment: Yes i did @ale13

Comment: Are you still encountering the same issue? @AbhishekKumar

Comment: I tried for several but it didn't worked out @ale13

Comment: Please check the [updated code](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes) - can you try this and confirm you are still getting the error? Moreover, did you end up creating any cloud functions as well?